# Help me fix this messed up HTML table please

Tags: html

I have a simmple HTML table that I just cant seem to fix.

I am trying to display data like so:

```
                                  <-Previous Next->
                              51 to 100 of 10151 records
```

Below is the html code. I have taken out the dynamic language part that adds 'Previous' depending on what page the user is on:

**EDIT:** After all the responses I've changed the code to following. but still alignment is the same. >_<

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr align="center">
       <td bgcolor="#ffffff" color="white" align="center" colspan="2">
       <!--some form elements go here!-->
       <!--I just replaced tags with some text for testing-->
       <font face="Arial" size="2"><strong>Previous</strong></font>
        Previous
       </td>
       <td bgcolor="#ffffff" color="white" align="center" colspan="2">
        Next
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
       <td align="center"><font face="arial" size="2"><b>51 to 100 of 10151</b> </font>
       </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Expected output is above but what I am getting from the code is:

```
                 Previous            Next Group   
         51 to 100 of 10151 Households
```

I have been doing trial and error for quite some time now so need some help!

Comment: Using tables for layout is BAD.

Comment: @ChssPly76, it's not "best practices" anymore, but it's hardly BAD.

Comment: I'm in deep shit...maybe later on I'll take time out to change table layout to div layout. but for now hoping for this to be resolved

Comment: Whether or not using tables for layout is bad in principle, in this instance its use seems totally gratuitous. The solution using divs would be much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need table cells for both the `Previous` and `Next` text? Why not just put them in the same `<td>`?

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr align="center">
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" color="white" align="center" colspan="2">
        Previous Next
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td align="center"><font face="arial" size="2"><b>51 to 100 of 10151</b></font></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Did I miss a requirement?

Comment: +1 Very clever...worked around the requirements and showed him the light!

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the attributes:

```
Value="<<Previous"
```

should be

```
Value="&lt;&lt;Previous"
```

Comment: I changed the code to remove attributes completely but still the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Add a `colspan="2"` to the `td` in the second row.

Comment: And get rid of the colspan="2" elsewhere unless you need them for something we're not being shown, otherwise the second row should be colspan="4".

Answer (score 1):

use html entities to show < and > characters on the screen. < is `&lt;` and > is `&gt;`

Something that will also help is to use an editor that has syntax highlighting and you can catch these mistakes more easily

Answer (score 1):

For starters, after your first row (<tr>...</tr>), you fail to start another row.  Also, you need to column span the cell in the next row to make it take up the space under both cells in the row above it, not just the first one:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center" colspan="2"><font....>....</td>
</tr>
```

Also, you have other HTML issues (you need to escape out HTML entities such as < and > if you want them to appear in your text), so you might want to run that through an editor that understands HTML or otherwise validate it.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some tags and quotes, and escape characters as others have mentioned.

You can try using the htmlvalidator at w3c.

http://validator.w3.org/#validate-by-input

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr align="center">
       <td bgcolor="#ffffff" color="white" align="center">
            <!--some form elements go here!-->
            <font face="Arial" size="2"><strong>Previous</strong></font>
            <Input id='previuesButton' Type="image"  alt="Previous" src="/eiv/images/prev.gif" value="&lt;&lt;Previous" name=previuesButton ACCESSKEY="B">
       </td>
       <td bgcolor="#ffffff" color="white" align="center">
            <font face="Arial" size="2"><strong>Next Group</strong></font>
            <Input id='nextButton' alt="Next" Type="image" src="/eiv/images/next.gif" Value="Next&gt;&gt;" name=nextButton ACCESSKEY="B">
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td align="center" colspan="2"><font face="arial" size="2"><b>51 to 100 of 10151</b> </font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You were missing a starting and ending row tag as well as a colspan in the bottom column.  Try the above to see if that works out for you.  Also you need to swap the less than and greater than characters for their equivalents (as shown above).

Comment: tried your code and put it here: http://jsbin.com/oduda
I dont want Previous and Next to have such a huge gap between them. just want them to be close to each ohter

Comment: change the align="center" on the previous to be "right" and the align="center" on the next to be "left".

Answer (score 0):

Are you having a problem with greater than or less than signs?

Try this:

```
    <table width="100%" border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr align="center">
       <td bgcolor="#ffffff" color="white" align="center">
       <!--some form elements go here!-->
       <font face="Arial" size="2"><strong>&lt;-Previous</strong></font>
        <Input id='previuesButton' Type="image"  alt="Previous" src="/eiv/images/prev.gif"     
        Value="<<Previous" name=previuesButton ACCESSKEY="B">
       </td>
       <td bgcolor="#ffffff" color="white" align="center">
       <font face="Arial" size="2"><strong>Next Group-&gt;</strong></font>
       <Input id='nextButton' alt="Next" Type="image" src="/eiv/images/next.gif" Value="     
       Next>>     "name=nextButton ACCESSKEY="B">
       </td>
    </tr>
       <td align="center"><font face="arial" size="2"><b>51 to 100 of 10151</b> </font>
       </td>
</tbody>
```

That help?

Answer (score 0):

Your code, with:

1. The missing  tags for the second row added in.
2. The arrows converted to html entities.
3. The missing quotes added in.
4. Your spelling corrected.

Try running your html through the w3c validator next time. Hope it helps.

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr align="center">
       <td bgcolor="#ffffff" color="white" align="center">
       <font face="Arial" size="2"><strong>Previous</strong></font>
        <Input id='previousButton' Type="image"  alt="Previous" src="/eiv/images/prev.gif"     
        Value="&lt;&lt;Previous" name="previousButton" ACCESSKEY="B">
       </td>
       <td bgcolor="#ffffff" color="white" align="center">
       <font face="Arial" size="2"><strong>Next Group</strong></font>
       <Input id='nextButton' alt="Next" Type="image" src="/eiv/images/next.gif" Value="     
       Next &gt;&gt;" name="nextButton" ACCESSKEY="B"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td align="center" colspan="2"><font face="arial" size="2"><b>51 to 100 of 10151</b></font>
       </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks. I tried your code as well and put it here http://jsbin.com/oroze  Is there any way to reduce the gap between previous and next. and have them close to each other